# How can we truncate a power series and convert it to a polynomial in sympy?

Tags: math, sympy

I would like to truncate a power series in sympy and use the result as a polynomial. What I'm doing now is a bit ugly (example for degree 4):

```
truncated_series = 0
for i,term in zip(range(5), f.lseries()):
    truncated_series += term
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
In [1]: f = sin(x)

In [2]: s = series(f, x, 0, 5)

In [3]: s
Out[3]: 
     3        
    x     / 5\
x - -- + O\x /
    6         

In [4]: s.removeO()
Out[4]: 
   3    
  x     
- -- + x
  6
```

These steps are straightforward.

If you instead instist on using *.lseries()*, then you could do:

```
In [5]: import itertools  

In [6]: Add(*itertools.islice(f.lseries(), 5))
Out[6]: 
   9       7      5    3    
  x       x      x    x     
------ - ---- + --- - -- + x
362880   5040   120   6
```

Explanation: *islice* picks 5 elements from the generator, which are passed as arguments to the *Add* class, which managed SymPy's additions.

Comment: Thanks! Both removeO and islice, neither of which I knew, are very useful!